# Group by error in SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
select row_number() over(order by Name) as Number,Name
,COUNT(Code) as Tqty from WorkTbl group by Name order by Tqty
,COUNT(Code) as Tqty2 from WorkTbl Where Status <> 'AA' and Status <> 'BB' group by Name order by Tqty2
```

and I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

but if I run this query it works fine:

```
select row_number() over(order by Name) as Number,Name
,COUNT(Code) as Tqty from WorkTbl group by Name order by Tqty
```

I must have all columns in the query

How to do it ?

Comment: Can you clean up your sample code so that it's valid SQL?  You've got two FROM and two GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: This is not the place for "I don't know how to write a query" questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like

```
select row_number() over(order by Name) as Number,Name
,COUNT(Code) as Tqty,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Status<>'AA' AND Status <>'BB' THEN Code END) AS Tqty2
from WorkTbl group by Name order by Tqty
```